# How to disable typeahead in Ubuntu 22.04 gnome file manager (Files)

Tags: gnome, ibus

the typeahead search is a bit obnoxious and I would love to disable it. Anyone has an idea how to do that please?

It's very slow as per this topic: [Typeahead search slowed down in 22.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1440229/typeahead-search-slowed-down-in-22-10) and this bug ticket: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1996652

However, I am running on the 22.04.3 and the ibus repo is not working anymore...